# Can someone identify this chandelier from the UL tag on it?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

My favorite crystal chandelier's (purchased in 1997) arm broke during a move and I trying to figure out how to replace the arm. It's been in a box 5 years because I can’t get anywhere.

The UL tag has numbers. I went to a chandelier parts website thinking I’ll just get a new arm  but measurements don't really match.

The tag says Crystal Clear Industries and I purchased it myself but I can’t find anything on this company.

[image]

Comment: Designs usually change a lot in 25 years, so there might not be "new" replacements/repair parts.  A very fast search just for crystal clear industries, does seem to bring up quite a few interesting possibilities.  Unknown if they will be useful.  Depending on the damage and what the arm is made of, a repair of it might be possible.  If you can post a picture of the damage it might help.

Comment: A focused picture of the entire chandelier and a couple of close ups of the broken bits may garner you some suggestions on how to go about repairing it yourself. Also, the labeling in French (on a product from 1997), might indicate a Canadian manufacturer, so be sure to consider that in your research.

Comment: Also, the labeling in French for a 1997 product indicates that the company could be Canadian, so include that in your searches. Don't forget that the company could have closed in the intervening 25 years or have been bought up (with the name dropped) by another company.

Comment: Unfortunately the UL File number given fails to turn up any results on UL's Product IQ site. It is unclear if the UL Listing shown is fake, if it has a typo, or if some issue is making the record not show up online. You could try contacting the UL Solutions Customer Experience Center. Phone number: 1-877-854-3577 — Email: CEC@ul.com  They should be able to determine if the listing is fake or has a typo, etc.

Comment: Seems like Crystal Clear Industries no longer exists: "Crystal Clear was purchased by Salton Inc. in 2004 and they have since discontinued production." They seem to have been quite high end lamps.

Answer (score 1):

Even though UL looks at "everything", I think it is likely that the UL listing covers multiple devices/designs but with common general characteristics. Since you haven't found anything on the company, it likely either went out of business or was acquired by another company sometime before every little company had a web site. I doubt you will suddenly find success in getting an exact replacement. In fact, even if you find the company under a new name, it is quite possible that they will no longer have replacement parts for a 20+ year old model.

My recommendations are:

- Used - Check all kinds of places that may have used lighting fixtures and parts. At the national (global really) level is eBay. At the local level it could include thrift stores, antique stores (26 years isn't really antique, but it isn't "new"), Habitat for Humanity ReStore and similar stores and been-there-forever hardware stores (if you still have any in your area).
- Parts - Try a lighting store. Not the lighting section of Home Depot/Lowes/etc. but a store that sells to contractors, architects, designers, etc. Every large city has them, similar to electrical and plumbing supply houses. If they sell repair parts rather than just new fixtures then they may have or be able to get a compatible part. (They may sell repair parts because if you have a hotel with 100 matching light fixtures and one breaks you want to fix it rather than replace it with a new model that looks different from all the others.)
- Handcrafted - This can get expensive, but may be worth it to you. Find a artist, handyman or tinkerer who can fashion a replacement to match the rest of the chandelier.